# Variation of the effective two-dimensional action

Tags: gravity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

I am trying to derive the Einstein equations in section 3.1 of [Andrew Strominger- Les Houches lectures on Black Holes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9501071.pdf)
where one has to vary the action
$$
\mathcal{S} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int{d^2x\sqrt{-g}\left(e^{-2\phi}R_{
\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}+e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi g^{\mu\nu}+2\lambda^2\right)}
$$
the variation of these with respect to the metric then gives
$$
\delta\mathcal{S}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int{d^2x\left(\delta\sqrt{-g}\left(e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}+2e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi g^{\mu\nu}+2\lambda^2\right)+\sqrt{-g}\left[\delta(e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu})+2e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}\right]\right)}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int{d^2x\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}\left(e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}+2e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi g^{\mu\nu}+2\lambda^2\right)+\sqrt{-g}\left[e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+4e^{-2\phi}(\nabla\phi)^2g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}-2e^{-2\phi}\Box\phi g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}-4e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}+2e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}\right]\right)}
$$
where I have used the Palatini identity
$$
\delta(e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}) = e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+e^{-2\phi}\delta R_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\nu}= e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+e^{-2\phi}g_{\mu\nu}\Box\delta g^{\mu\nu}-e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\delta g^{\mu\nu}
$$
and then by integrating by parts and assuming boundary terms vanish we get
$$
\delta(e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu})= \text{boundary terms}+e^{-2\phi}R_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+4e^{-2\phi}(\nabla\phi)^2g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}-2e^{-2\phi}\Box\phi g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}-4e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}+2e^{-2\phi}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\phi \delta g^{\mu\nu}
$$

Now setting the variation of the action equal to zero and multiplying by a factor of $e^{2\phi}$ we get
$$
R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R \equiv G_{\mu\nu} = 2\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi-2\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\phi-3 g_{\mu\nu}(\nabla\phi)^2+2\Box\phi g_{\mu\nu}+\lambda^2 g_{\mu\nu}e^{2\phi}
$$

The author on the other hand gives the equation
$$
G_{\mu\nu}= 2\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\phi-2\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi+3g_{\mu\nu}(\nabla\phi)^2-2g_{\mu\nu}\Box\phi-\lambda^2 g_{\mu\nu} e^{2\phi}
$$

I went through the calculation a million times but for the life of me I can't figure out where the sign difference of the 3 last terms comes from. Is this a different convention that the author uses?

Comment: The first two terms also have the same sign change, so you and Andy Strominger differ on an *overall* sign change

Comment: Yes but the $G_{\mu\nu}$ on the LHS doesn't have the same sign. Is it true that $G_{\mu\nu}=-G_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: No. But it's easy to get the sign wrong when calculating $T^{\mu\nu}$ by varying $g_{\mu\nu}$ or  $T_{\mu\nu}$ by varying $g^{\mu\nu}$.  You need to remember that  that $\delta g^{\mu\nu}=- g^{\mu\sigma} \delta g_{\sigma\tau} g^{\tau\nu}$. Consequently raising and lowering the indices on $T$ requires a sign change in the definition from the variation.

Comment: I have looked for a mistake like that as well, but still I can't seem to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Andy could have made a mistake!